# Is it possible for a hash in SHA-256 to have more than 8 digits?

Tags: hash, sha-256, cryptocurrency

Is it ever possible for a hash to have more than 8 digits in SHA-256?

Comment: What do you mean 'have more than 8 digits'?  Have more than eight characters between '0' and '9' when expressed in hex?

Comment: Can the actual hash itself be more than 8 digits in length;
ex. Is 6a09e667b possible, having a 9 digit length?

Answer (score 1):

A SHA-256 hash always has exactly 256 bits of output. That is 32 bytes, or 64 hex characters long. For example the text "abc" has the hash "ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad".

Thus, a SHA-256 hash will always have more than 8 ASCII characters of output.